# utilizo es laravel 5.8,. el problema que no me guarda la imagen que deseo subir ala carpeta storage/app/public,

Tags: laravel-5, mysqli, php7, php5, laravel-6

**aqui tengo la ruta en web.php y tambien la vista config con el formulario, el input file tiene name="image_path"**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**luego las configuraciones en el archivo filesystem.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y luego la logica el controlador con la clase usuarioController y el metodo update**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**tengo el error en pantalla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**nota:** si comento esta parte del codigo  l**linea 51 Storage::disk('public')->put($image_path_name, File::get($image_path));**  la logica sigue todo normal no ocasiona bug, solo cuando la tengo sin comentar que no guarda la imagen en la carpeta de laravel pero el nombre de la imagen que es extraido en el codigo     **$image_path = $request->file('image_path');** si se guarda en la tabla de mi base de datos

Comment: solo no utilices `File::get` y dejalo con `image_path`

Comment: En el cuando eliges el disk del storage dejalo como `Storage::disk('users')`